# Small proble with flask HTML and python

Tags: html, flask

Hi my project **must be done in python**.I'm doing a translator from the DNA to amino acids. I decided to make a code in notebook, save the file '.py' and write another code, that will transwer user from notebook to a website. And here the problem started. Everything works, but few code lines are on the interface.Unfortunatelly I'm writting in polish, but folks like you can easily deal with that. So here is a ss from the page that user will use
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fstd8.png). I want do delete unnecesary lines, and the most important the buttin doesn't translate the codons into amino acids. Here is a ss of the code that transwer the user into a page (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAcHC.png). And the last thing is the actual code that will transfer DNA into amino acids[1 part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbfno.png)[2 part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32J3z.png)

Okay so I tried asking Chat GPT to help me (no succes). I expect: when you press the button the DNA, that you' ve written in the box is going to transwer into codons and codons are the type of form where you can call the amino acids. So in the short way: you write the DNA fragment and the code translates it into amino acids.I don't know if the 2 codes mentioned above must be i the same code or apart files. If you decide to help, you can write a code in englis and I can translate it on my own

BTW If you want to help me, you have two weeks max to improve this code. I would be happy if someone helped me:) I'm sexteen so don't write super mega hyper hard and long code unless you need to

Comment: SO is *not* a code-writing service. Please have a look at [ask] - "*I'm writting in polish, but folks like you can easily deal with that*", that's a big no. SO is an English only website.

Comment: FYI: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. If you have a specific question about *code you have already written*, we will be happy to take a look.